# Check if form is completed before activating submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a form where a user has to fill out several fields and then click sign up. However, I want JavaScript to check if the passwords match, and if they don't or a field is left empty to put the signup button into a disabled state with Bootstrap. However, nothing is working. Here is my code:
JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/jbe65/

```
echo '
<h3>Don\'t have an account yet? Sign up now!</h3>
<form action="signup.php" method="post">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email">
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="pass" id="pass">
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Again" name="passver" id="passver">
          <br><br>
            <p id="submit">button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up/button></p>
      </form>
      <script>
      var empty = "";
      var email = $(\'#email\').val()\;
      var pass = $(\'#pass\').val()\;
      var passver = $(\'#passver\').val()\;
      if (empty == email)
      {
      if (pass != passver)
      {
      document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML=\'<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" disabled="disabled">Sign Up</button>\';
      }
      }
      </script>
      ';
```

Comment: Where u calling that jsscript? hard to undersatand can u make a fiddle ?

Comment: Don't disable button if its empty even keep button disable and once all data is filled make it enable. that way its much easier to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest make the button lookalike disable (by css) and once all the cond pass can make it enable (by css)..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#formid").on("submit", function (e) {  
    var empty = "";
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var pass = $('#pass').val();
    var passver = $('#passver').val();
    if (empty == email || pass !== passver)
    {
       alert("please enter valid email and password.");
       e.preventDefault();
    }
    else
   {
       //u can call this in textbox blur also... 
       $("#sub").removeClass("disable");
    }    
});
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jbe65/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using PHP. If so, you can replace the `echo` statement with a closing PHP bracket `?>` to escape the parser. It's generally easier to deal with.

To answer the question at hand, since you are using jQuery, there is no need to change the innerHTML of the `p` tag, just use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function, like so:

```
?>
    <h3>Don't have an account yet? Sign up now!</h3>
    <form action="signup.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="pass" id="pass">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Again" name="passver" id="passver">

    <p id="submit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button></p>
    </form>
    <script>
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var pass = $('#pass').val();
        var passver = $('#passver').val();
        if ("" == email)
        {
            if (pass != passver)
            {
                $('#submit button').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }
    </script>
<?php
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Neha's had a working JSfiddle and an alert, etc

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HTML5 , Put "Required" and then the submit button will not be loaded if there is an empty field Ex :